# Loading shared libraries in IRIX UNIX: failing due to ENOSPC

Tags: shared-libraries, irix

I am running into problems on an ancient *IRIX 6.5* system. First a program did not find a shared library, because I moved the program from one machine to another.

I then fetched the library and put it in a lib folder in my user's home and adapted `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` accordingly. Now `rld` finds the library but `elfmap` fails with a for me cryptic error:

```
138076:/s/masslib/pro/masslib: rld: Error: elfmap: couldn't map /usr/people/guest/lib/libndguisvr.so: Not enough space
138076:/s/masslib/pro/masslib: rld: Fatal Error: Cannot Successfully map soname 'libndguisvr.so' under any of the filenames /usr/people/guest/lib/libndguisvr.so:/usr/lib32/libndguisvr.so:/usr/lib32/internal/libndguisvr.so:/lib32/libndguisvr.so:/opt/lib32/libndguisvr.so:
```

What does the *Not enough space* mean? Not enough memory? Is there anything I can do about that?

Is there anybody out there on SO who still knows IRIX UNIX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does the Not enough space mean?

It means that some system call that `rld` executed failed with `ENOSPC` error.

For example, `write` system call [may fail](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/write.html) with `ENOSPC` if there is not enough space on the disk.

Your first task should be to figure out *which* system call is failing. Probably you can use `strace` or `par` to find that out.

> I then fetched the library

Note that if the library came from a newer machine than the one you are running on, all kinds of weird errors are somewhat expected: UNIX systems support backward compatibility (older binaries continue to work on newer systems), but not the reverse.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I fetched the IRIX versions using `uname -a`. For the destination machine it shows: `IRIX DEST 6.5 04191226 IP32` and for the source machine where I copied the library from `IRIX SOURCE 6.5 10181059 IP28`. AFAIK, the last IRIX version was 6.5.30.